# Get rid of the widget Item Class="widget-item"

Tags: functions, widgets

> Can we please stick ourselves to the genuine solution, not a slipshod
>   remedy. The objective of this question is to completely get rid of the
>   class "widget-item". please do not post compromised solutions like
>   manipulating CSS etc else the objective of posting the question will
>   be defied.

I want to get rid of this class="**widget-item**" because this is creating extra margin/padding. Please see the image.[image]

I want to get rid of this class, but not `div` as it might rupture the design.

I am sure there should be some method to remove this because when we write widgets for menus this is possible like this →

```
'container'   => 'nav',
'container_class' => 'footer-menu'
```

we can change `div` to `nav` and also insert our own class "**footer-menu**".

Live Link where this is happening could be seen [here](http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/).

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way would be to overwrite this in your CSS file, for instance like this:

```
.widgettitle {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Alternatively you can change the name of the class when registering your widget (possibly in your functions.php file) - look for the `'before_title'` parameter. Here's and example form the original twentysexteen template:

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebar', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your sidebar.', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
```

Comment: Hi There, the question is about this class → "widget-item" This class seems to be coming from somewhere else. Probably we have to handle them with some array manipulation or something else. I am too naive in WordPress and programming world.

Comment: OK, you've changed the question, then if you like to change the behaviour of the "widget-item" class instead of "widget-title" - just overwrite it in your custom CSS file, but if we are still talking about [the site in the question](http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/) - there's currently no margin or padding set for the "widget-item" class as I see.

Comment: May be CSS footer Flex Property is conflicting with this.

Comment: On your screenshot (in the developer panel) you can clearly see that there is not padding or margin marked around the selected element. Could you upload another screenshot and mark the space that you'd like to get rid of.

Comment: Everything is clearly projected in the image provided. The genuine solution will be how to get rid of that class in its entirety.

Comment: Subscription widget takes now 50% of the space. If you want it to take 1/3 of the page width overwrite it in you custom CSS by for instance: `.site-footer .widget-item { flex: 1 0 33%; }`

Answer (score 2):

The `widget-item` class is in the $params for registered sidebars in the theme you are using. If you want to remove it and replace it with something else, you can by using the `dynamic_sidebar_params` filter or you can find it in your theme (if you are using a parent theme and not a child theme) and just change it, however the results may be not what you expect because the padding and margin is not coming from that class.

This filter below would be added last in your child theme's functions.php file AFTER all other functions and outside of all functions and after all includes/requires. In this example `widget-item` will be replaced by `my-widget-class` (which you would change). In this situation, `.widget-item` or any class here provides a global class to widgets and does not have padding or margin on it as in your image. When you use developer tools, you can clearly see that the child is the element with the margin and the padding.

```
function prefix_filter_widget_div_wrappper( $params ) {

    $params[0]['before_widget'] = '<div class="my-widget-class %2$s">' ;

    $params[0]['after_widget']  = '</div>' ;

    return $params;

}
add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params' , 'prefix_filter_widget_div_wrappper' );
```

The issue in your situation is this `.newsletter` child of `.widget-item` and if you use CSS specificity, you can adjust the appearance for the location:

```
.newsletter {
    padding: 25px;
    ..etc.
}
```

Like this:

```
.site-footer .newseltter {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

### Conditional for `dynamic_sidebar_params` filter.

[Locate your registered sidebar ID by looking for where it is registered in your theme functions php file(s) parent or child](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar).

```
function prefix_filter_widget_div_wrappper_conditional( $params ) {

    //* where `register-sidebar-id` is the registered sidebar id (you would look for this in your theme's code)

    if ( 'registered-sidebar-id' === $params[0][ 'id' ] ) :

        $params[0]['before_widget'] = '<div class="my-widget-class %2$s">' ;

        $params[0]['after_widget']  = '</div>' ;

    endif;

    return $params;

}
add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params' , 'prefix_filter_widget_div_wrappper_conditional' );
```

Comment: what If i do not want any class?     $params[0]['before_widget'] = '<div class="my-widget-class %2$s">' ;

Comment: Empty the value: `$params[0]['before_widget'] = ' ' ;
    
    $params[0]['after_widget']  = ' ' ;`

Comment: No one does this. Global css for widgets and then specific css for sections.

Comment: Can you elaborate this?

Comment: Not right now. You would need to learn more CSS to understand why. Quicky if i use a class like widget-item then I can style all widget-items with one class then if I want to make widget-items look differently in the footer I would do this .site-footer .widget-item. So I don't have to write loads of CSS.

Comment: Okies. Is there a way to inject extra class here → <div class="widget-item"> like this →
<div class="widget-item extra-class"> However this should be done in such a way that it should only effect one widget in question, not all the widget that exists.

Comment: I updated the answer with the conditional. You will need to locate the registered id that is theme specific.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks! But I do not think so that this will make any difference because the new or extra class will again be implemented on the entire sidebar that means all the widgets will be impacted. The whole exercise was to focus on widget as an individual because the global or universal impact over all the widget is what is causing the issue. please correct me if I have misunderstood your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way would be to create a plugin that enqueues a jQuery script.

plugin.php

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Remove Widget Item Class
 */

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_266151_enqueue_scripts' );
wpse_266151_enqueue_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'remove-widget-item-class', 
    plugins_url( 'remove-widget-item-class.js', __FILE__ ), 
    [ 'jquery' ]
  );
}
```

remove-widget-item-class.js

```
jQuery( ".widget-item" ).removeClass( "widget-item" );
```